# Reference says he no longer gives references

Tags: references

I hadn't talked to guy in a while so I touched base with him to make sure I could still use him as a reference.

He said he has been coached to not give references because it opens him up for lawsuits from the candidate and the employer.

I am really floored because I needed a technical reference for a job opportunity I am being considered for.

Has anyone heard of this?

What can I do?

Comment: "Guy", was he your manager? Was he just your friend?

Comment: I think the bigger problem is you only have one reference.

Answer (score 6):

It's unfortunate but it's pretty common in the US for HR to instruct people not to give references.  That way, the company isn't at risk of a lawsuit if the reference isn't strong enough or says something negative.  Lots of large companies have blanket policies of not giving references.

There really isn't anything you can do other than asking someone else to be your reference.  If it looks odd not to offer a reference from this employer-- for example if you're providing a reference from someone you worked for while going to school rather than someone from your first long-term professional job-- you can always explain that the company has a blanket policy against references.  That's common enough that it shouldn't e an issue.

Comment: +1 and correct, as in my experience (US-Midwest) the larger the company the more rigid their HR polities, and I've come across a couple where there was company-wide instruction from HR to not give references.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a long shot, but try asking your reference if he would be prepared to give you a *personal* reference: in other words not in his work capacity, but simply as someone who knows you and is prepared to vouch for you. I've had this happen where official policy from the company was to forbid employees from giving references (and they would only give the standard "Yes he has worked here between these dates" reference"). However they cannot forbid someone from giving their own personal opinions about someone, as long as he's not acting on behalf of the company. He might say "In my opinion hforbess is a good worker and skilled in XYZ", without talking about what you did when you worked together. You, of course, would explain to your new employers your working relationship.

There is a certain amount of grey area to be negotiated, and a really strict company might forbid this, but it's worth a try. It's worked for me at least once.